# How can I run a Flask app hosted on a2hosting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have just setup my first Flask project hosted on a server (a2hosting). Now, I want to run on the web application my python script (calculating a few things and then redirects to other url).

But I am not sure how do I set it up on my app server in a2hosting?

```py
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...

from flask import Flask ,redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/set/<hana>')
def hello_world(hana):
    import googlemaps
    name = hana
    return redirect('http://mycamp.co.il/yesh/'+name , code=302)

@app.route('/hello')
def hiii():
    import pymongo

    def insert(myreq):
                dd={
            "hihi":"yes1yes"
        }
        myreq.insert_one(dd)
    return True
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://DETAILES.@routeplan-shard-00-00-d416l.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,routeplan-shard-00-01-d416l.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,routeplan-shard-00-02-d416l.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=routeplan-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true")
    mydb = client['router']
    myplan = mydb['planner']
    mydis =  mydb['distance']
    myopt =  mydb['optimal']
    myreq = mydb['request']
    myus = mydb['user']
    q=insert(myreq)


    return 'helo world %s' + q

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: can you describe more? I can't understand your problem well. Upload your code will be helpful

Comment: I made some progress and was able to connect my code using flask but now Im trying to run some short version of it and its not running:
`from flask import Flask ,redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/set/<hana>')
def hello_world(hana):
    import googlemaps
    name = hana
return redirect('http://mycamp.com/yesh/', code=302)
@app.route('/hello')
def hiii():
    import pymongo
    def insert(myreq):
    dd={"hihi":"yes1yes}
    myreq.insert_one(dd)
    return True
    q=insert(myreq)
    return 'helo world %s' + q
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)`

Comment: I think it's more likely to flask question rather then django. Sorry that I can't help you